# Add filters to search app on google play store with different variations of app name

Tags: android, google-play

I have a requirement where I need my app to displayed when searched by 2 different names.

Example: Facebook App can be search with facebook and face book (with white space).

But i have not found any reference to such a filter on the google play console.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you...

 - Make sure your most important keyword is included in the app title.
 - Google Play doesn’t let you submit keywords in the same way iOS does, so you need to include them in the text of your app description.
```